# to type "System.Int32"Error:"Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: mysql, powershell

I Run the this power shell script

```
"$InstallPh\Database\bin\mysql.exe" -'uroot' -'e''select status from zibcatalog.zibmonitor where backupset="$BACKUPSET" AND operation="ZIB_BACKUP";' > 'c:\\auto\\firstbackup-result.txt'
```

Powershell throws this error message:

```
Cannot convert value "\Database\bin\mysql.exe" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:2
+  "$InstallPh\Database\bin\mysql.exe" -'uroot' -'e''select status from zibcatalog ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question please. And Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Add "& " to the start of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems the way your trying to execute and pass the parameters to `MySQL.exe`. Try using the `&` operator to execute the exe file.

```
& "$InstallPh\Database\bin\mysql.exe" "-uroot -e'select status from zibcatalog.zibmonitor where backupset=`"$BACKUPSET`" AND operation=`"ZIB_BACKUP`";'" > 'c:\auto\firstbackup-result.txt'
```

Comment: i use the & but still  giving error message "   & : The term '\Database\bin\mysql.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &"$InstallPh\Database\bin\mysql.exe"-uroot -e
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\Database\bin\mysql.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

   "

Comment: It can't find the file `mysql.exe` try putting the absolute path in instead of '\Database\bin\mysql.exe' (e.g C:\....\bin\mysql.exe) and see if that works. Also check that 'mysql.exe' is in the folder.